# How to add text in superscript or subscript with python docx

Tags: python, unicode, docx, subscript, superscript

In the python docx quickstart guide (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can see that  it is possible to use the add_run-command and add bold text to a sentence.

```
document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
```

I would to use the same add_run-command but instead add text that is superscripted or subscripted.

Is this possible to achieve?

Any help much appreciated!

/V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `add_run()` returns a `Run` object that you can use to change [font options](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#font-objects).

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph('Normal text with ')

super_text = p.add_run('superscript text')
super_text.font.superscript = True

p.add_run(' and ')

sub_text = p.add_run('subscript text')
sub_text.font.subscript = True

document.save('test.docx')
```

[image]